# How implement I'm feeling Lucky in html?

Tags: html, forms

I have been trying to implement a form that goes to either normal Google search results or it's first search result. This is what I have tried.

```
<form action="https://google.com/search">
    <input type="text" name="q" class="box">
    <br>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Google Search" class="button">
        <input type="submit" value="I'm Feeling Lucky" class="button" formaction="https://google.com/search?&btnI=1">
    </div>
</form>
```

I know for a fact that if I search for let's say "AMD" then the I'm feeling lucky URL should be `"https://google.com/search?q=AMD&btnI=1"`

However, I am not able to add that `"&btn1"` at the end of the URL.

Comment: There is no reason to ever use `<input type="submit" />` instead of `<button type="submit">`.

Comment: That's some amazing finding. But you notice it's "&btn1". Shouldn't the browser just take you to that website directly?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It will work fine.

```
<form action="https://google.com/search">
    <input type="text" name="q" class="box">
    <br>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="btnK" value="Google Search" class="button">
        <input type="submit" name="btnI" value="I am Feeling Lucky" class="button">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked but since I am new to HTML could you please explain why it worked.

Comment: You need to put a name and a value for your submit button when you have more than one in your form because this is how POST requests work. I think that you are taking CS50W. If you are, you will know when more about that when you learn django.

Answer (score 5):

Use `<button type="submit">` instead:

```
<form action="https://google.com/search">
    <input type="text" name="q" class="box">
    <br />
    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="button">Google Search</button>
        <button type="submit" name="btnl" value="1" class="button">I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you please explain to me why adding name and value attributes worked. I am still a newbie.

Comment: Why is `<button>` better than `<input>`?

Comment: @BroVic `<button>` allows for arbitrary content and styled content, such as images and bold text. `<button>` also lets you specify an exact `value=“”` attribute separate from the button text, whereas `<input type=“submit”>` uses the `value=“”` attribute for the text displayed in the button AND the submitted value.

Comment: Okay, it's well noted.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you have to do is to give the name "btnI" to the input.

```
<input type="submit" value="I'm feeling lucky" name="btnI">
```